# Angularjs Create textarea with option add value from template

Tags: angularjs, textarea

I am trying to create a form textarea where the user can type text and can choose some predefined templates.

[image]

Here I want to allow the user to type in the `textarea` and also have the option to search for some predefined templates from the `input` box above that.

I can type but when adding value from the template it is not added to `textarea.

In the `input` box I have a `onChange` function to append the selected template to the `ng-model` of textarea.

The user may type few lines and then add some templates.

Templates are just few strings which were added by the user previously.

Template Example: "this is a wonderful place."

```
<input id="catg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text / Select Template" ng-model="newData" class="form-control" uib-typeahead="template as template.content for template in getTemplate($viewValue) | limitTo:8" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item)" typeahead-min-length="1" typeahead-no-results="noResults">

<textarea ng-model="userValue"></textarea>
```

js:

```
$scope.onSelect = function(data) {
    $scope.userValue.concat(data)
}
```

Comment: You want to add the value present inside a template which was chosen by a user to be printed in textarea?

Comment: @Vivz yes, the selected value should be printed in the textarea and the user should be able to enter text directly into it also

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried

Comment: @Vivz I have added the html and js that i have tried

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/fzre25nb/107/ ?

Comment: @Vivz Yes something like this but in the input box i need to use `uib-typeahead` which will fetch data from a server

Comment: Idk abut uib-typehead but you can use the same logic and implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch for any changes in the ng-model value for text area and update the textarea accorddingly

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.txt='';
    
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.txt = '';
    };
    $scope.$watch('template.text',function(oldval,newval){
      if(newval!==undefined)
       $scope.txt= newval + "\n";
    
    })
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input style="float:left;" type="text" ng-model="template.text">
<textarea id="textarea" ng-model="txt" style="float:left;">
    
</textarea>

    <div>{{txt}}</div>

<!--<button id='btn' ng-click="txt=''">Reset textarea</button>-->
    <button id='btn' ng-click="reset()">Reset textarea</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model for the input field is newData. Therefore, pass that value into onSelect() function.

```
<input id="catg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text / Select Template" ng-model="newData" class="form-control" uib-typeahead="template as template.content for template in getTemplate($viewValue) | limitTo:8" typeahead-on-select="onSelect(newData)" typeahead-min-length="1" typeahead-no-results="noResults">

<textarea ng-model="userValue"></textarea>
```